# Custom int size other than using <stdint.h>

Tags: c, int, size

How can you get a custom-sized integer data type? Is there any other answer than using `<stdint.h>` types like `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` and are these types platform-independent?

Comment: ... are these types platform-independent? --> The existence of `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` _is_ platform-dependent. Although few machines today do not have 16-bit integers.  Please provide an example of _custom-sized integer data type_ you would like.

Comment: `<stdint.h>` is the way to get integer types of specified sizes. Why are you looking for a different solution? I'm not saying there's no good reason, but knowing what *your* reason is would make it easier to give you a useful answer. What problem are you trying to solve? (If you're just curious, that's fine, but please say so.)

Comment: @KeithThompson It's an exam question. I just want to answer it right. I could ask "Is there a way of creating 256 bit integer?" or somehting like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is *mostly* No. `<stdint.h>` provides integers of specific sizes available on a given platform, <s>but there's no standard way to get, say, a 20-bit integer</s> but you can specify arbitrary size *smaller* than those provided by `<stdint.h>` by using bitfields. The following provides a 20-bit unsigned int that works as you would expect it to, though the interface is a little clunky.

```
struct uint20_s {
   unsigned int val : 20;
};
```

Broadly speaking it is non-trivial to implement integer semantics for word-sizes larger than those supported by the underlying hardware. There is [an entire class of libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) dedicated to working with arbitrary precision numerics.

Comment: Doesn't this count: `struct s { unsigned long twentybit:20; };` ?

Comment: @LxerLx I thought the overflow semantics for bitfields was different but consulting the standard it appears I'm wrong. So yes, that works as long as you want an arbitrary type _smaller_ than max word length

Comment: @LxerLx `struct s { unsigned twentybit:20; };` works when `unsigned` is, say, 32 bits. (`unsigned` might be 16-bit.)   `unsigned long twentybit:20;` and `uint32_t val : 20;` rely on implementation-defined aspects.  "A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed int`,
`unsigned int` or some other implementation-defined type.", not necessarily "smaller than max word length".

Comment: There is a standard way now... on 4/21/2020 clang released `_ExtInt` which allows you to make things like 20-bit ints. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411865/how-do-you-use-clangs-new-custom-size-int-feature

Answer (score 5):

You can get a custom-width integer as a member in a structure by using a bit field, as in:

```
struct foo { int x : 13; } f;
```

The maximum width supported for a bit-field is depends on both the implementation and the base type (`int` above) used for it.

The widths of standard types such as `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` are of course not implementation-dependent, but whether they are provided by an implementation is.

Comment: As an additional note to the answer above, I would like to point out that it is implementation-defined whether the bit-field (`x` in the `struct foo` above) is `signed` or `unsigned`, since a _plain_ `int` is used to define it.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but... There is a good solution! Clang has this new feature (released on 4/24/2020), which allows you to declare custom size integers. You have to use the `_ExtInt` keyword. An example:

```
_ExtInt(13) foo;
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411865/how-do-you-use-clangs-new-custom-size-int-feature/61411866#61411866) for some more details.