# Is there a gcc function to add two large numbers for C?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to add two numbers in C. My code is

```
#define type unsigned
type add(type a, type b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Code corresponding to above code in assembly makes use of a single add instruction (https://godbolt.org/ & ARM GCC 8.3.1). However when I changed the `type` to `unsigned long long`, code was bit obfuscated to understand; But, I believe it makes use of some `ldm` and then asks hardware to add complete vectors (or arrays). Similarly my next question was: is it possible to add two numbers where digits count in each number will be in the order of 1000s? It isn't hard to design a function and make it work, and I found many codes on internet which do this. But, I think compiler writes better code than us,

- so are there any gcc built-in functions which can do this job?
- In fact, does gcc provide such functions for all the 5 integer arithmetic operations?

Comment: As far as I know, the answer is no.  You might want to just use a language like Ruby or Python that already supports arbitrarily big integers.  Or use the [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: clang has such a feature, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61411865/how-do-you-use-clangs-new-custom-size-int-feature, but it has issues.  (1) You have to choose the size at compile time; (2) division and mod aren't implemented for arbitrarily large sizes (3) the code it generates is rather naive (always fully unrolled and inlined), so it is often worse than hand-tuned code from gmp or the like.

Comment: "But, I think compiler writes better code than us": True in many cases, but arbitrary-precision arithmetic tends to be an exception, as it relies on machine constructs (add with carry, etc) that don't exist in C and that the compiler isn't used to trying to optimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no compiler support in GCC for arbitrary-precision arithmetic. You would need to use a library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). If you can use C++ instead of C, you can get a more "natural" API (with arithmetic operators, etc.) by using a library like [Boost Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

[GCC does support, as an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html), the types `__int128` and `unsigned __int128`, which can be used like any other integral type, but these only provide capacity for 38 decimal digits.

Edit: Also, as an aside, don't use macros (like `#define type unsigned`) to rename types. Instead this should be written with the `typedef` keyword like so: `typedef unsigned type;`